# Is it possible to display a child element over a parent's y-scrollbar using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a selection box built with `<ul>` and `<li>` elements. Some list items are wider than the parent box, so I added an `:after` pseudo-element to overlay them with the full content on `:hover`.

It all works *great*, except when the `<ul>` element has a vertical scrollbar. Then the overlay gets hidden and a horizontal scrollbar appears.

Is there some way to display the child overlay *over* the parent's vertical scrollbar?

JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/x9TZB/14/ (works in Chrome, but currently crashing IE10 for me... weird.)

**UPDATE:**

I've been able to solve my problem (mostly) by adding another `<div>` element to the DOM, positioning it over the `<li>` element, and setting up a bunch of events and timers. There are still some rough edges; it's not perfect by any means (especially since IE doesn't support `pointer-events:none`).

I'll leave this question open, in case anyone finds a working solution -- and if not, then perhaps as a tacit suggestion for an update to the HTML5 standard layout rules :-)

---

Code is pasted here in case the JSFiddle page ever disappears. Try adding/removing the "scrolling" class from the `<ul>` element to see the difference.

```
-- CSS --

ul {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
    width: 150px;
    font: 12px verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    overflow-x: visible;
}
ul.scrolling {
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-right: -16px;
}
li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow: hidden;
}
ul.scrolling > li {
    padding-right: 6px;
}
li:hover {
    background-color: #c7e0ff;
    overflow: visible;
}
li:hover:after {
    content: attr(contents);
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    padding: 0 5px;
    z-index: 999999;
    background-color: #c7e0ff;
}


-- HTML --

<ul class="scrolling">
    <li>Lorem ipsum</li>
    <li>Dolor sit amet</li>
    <li>Consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
    <li>Sed do eiusmod tempor</li>
    <li>Incididunt ut labore et dolore</li>
    <li>Magna aliqua</li>
    <li>Ut enim ad minim veniam</li>
    <li>Quis nostrud exercitation</li>
    <li>Ullamco laboris nisi ut</li>
    <li>Aliquip ex ea commodo consequat</li>
    <li>Duis aute irure dolor</li>
    <li>In reprehenderit</li>
    <li>In voluptate velit esse</li>
    <li>Cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur</li>
    <li>Excepteur sint occaecat</li>
    <li>Cupidatat non proident</li>
    <li>Sunt in culpa qui officia</li>
    <li>Deserunt mollit anim id est laborum</li>
</ul>


-- JavaScript (using jQuery) --

//Make sure this is run after the DOM is ready.
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).attr('contents', $(this).html());
});
```

Comment: You'd have to append the child element to something outside its initial parent, such as the body.

Comment: @Interrobang: Thanks, that's a start. However, once the element is in place, `mouseout` is triggered on the `<ul>` when the user nudges the mouse. Using `pointer-events:none` isn't an option, since I must support IE9. So, using a CSS `:after` element for the overlay would be far more elegant, if at all possible.

Comment: Seems like a hard task. Have you tried using a div container around the ul, with appropriate border style set, and then scroll the div rather than the list?

Comment: @lukeocom: yes, I have tried that. It seems that the overflow and scroll behavior is identical regardless of how deeply nested the child element is.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to achieved the affect you are after. It seems a little 'jittery' but perhaps this is a good starting point for you.

I contained the list within a div with the overflow-y set to scroll. I then set the position of the li to absolute on hover with an increased z-index. Changing the z-index seems to cause the 'jitteryness'. 
This worked in Chrome.

Have a look - http://jsfiddle.net/x9TZB/17/

css changes

```
li:hover{z-index:1;position:absolute;}
#listContainer{z-index:0;width:150px;height:200px;border:1px solid red;overflow-y:scroll;overflow-x:visible;}
```

**UPDATE:** This works without the containment div. Just remove the div from the above fiddle.. Also tested it in IE9 and seems to work OK too.