# Unordered list within div tag does not display outside the enclosing div

Tags: html, css

I have an unordered list held within a div tag.

I have a tree like structure of list elements containing additional lists e.g.

```
<ul>
 <li>
  <ul>
   <li>
   </li>
  </ul>
 <li>
</ul>
```

When i hover over a list element that contains a sublist the sublist displays as a popup within the containing div element. This list can be up to three layers deep which presents a problem. The width i have to display my containing div is limited (170px width/400px height)so i'd like the pop up list elements to extend beyond the containing div however I'm struggling to get this working.

Basically I'd like the vertical scroll bar to be present but the width scroll bar hidden. Overflow on the width should extend outside the containing div. I've tried variations on overflow-y/x but I can't seem to get a balance that does what I need. i also haven't been able to get the pop up

elements to extend outside the containing dev.

jsfiddle below to provide an example. And an image of the issue below:

http://jsfiddle.net/sapatos/tvZUX/1/

[image]

Comment: Make sure overflow is not set to 'hidden', but honestly since your elements are nested, I don't know if this is going to work. If you're going to do popups you might try not nesting them and just using js to make them popup in the right position.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/techsin/WgDmv/2/ like this

Comment: Fully related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15937642/is-it-possible-to-display-a-child-element-over-a-parents-y-scrollbar-using-css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The scroll effect is due to the following CSS code:

```
overflow-y: scroll;
```

If you take it out, the scroll will go away for the width.

The idea of putting a sub menu within a submenu, etc.. can be seen in this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/BVvc6/182/).

You can also try this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tvZUX/4/)

I altered your code to reposition everything using margin-left. But to be honest, your code is extremely vast, I would suggest taking a portion of it and then working on it. My last thing I want to note is to not get too confused when you start going further into the sub menus.. it is definitely a complex thought process.

**EDIT** Here is the last example I can give you... I do want to caution you that this may not be exact in every browser and there may be some better way to positioning everything. Here it is:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tvZUX/5/)

This does however become much harder when the contents inside of the li tags are different. An example of this is when you have only one line of text vs two lines of text, which will render the absolute positioning utterly useless. It may be easier to style these vertically than horizontally and there could be a better solution but that could entail using JavaScript or a derivative of that language.